# Сортировка родителей по содержанию дочерних элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно на js/jquery сделать сортировку элементов по содержанию дочерних элементов?

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="time">20:40</span>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <span class="time">10:40</span>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <span class="time">23:25</span>
</div>
```

Чтобы на выходе элементы отсортировали от меньшего к большему?

Answer (score 3):

Массив в JavaScript имеет метод [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), который может принимать необязательным параметром функцию для сортировки массива. В этой функции Вы можете реализовать какую угодно реализацию сортировки. Для Вашего случая это может выглядеть примерно так:

```js
/* Преобразует строку в число */
var strToInt = function (str) {
    var parsed = parseInt(str, 10);
    return isNaN(parsed) ? 0 : parsed;
},
/* Извлекает строку из элемента и преобразует в Date. */
getDate = function (elem) {
    // "извлекаем" текст из элемента, 
    // разрезаем строку по двоеточию,
    // каждый элемент полученного массива преобразуем в число
    var arr = $(elem).text().split(":").map(strToInt);
    return new Date(0, 0, 0, arr[0], arr[1]);
},
/* Функция сортировки */
sortParents = function (a, b) {
    var d1 = getDate(a);
    var d2 = getDate(b);
    if (d1.getTime() === d2.getTime()) {
        return 0;
    }
    // Для изменения направления сортировки здесь
    // можно параметризировать сравнение
    return d1 < d2 ? -1 : 1;
};

var $elems = $("div.parent");
    $elems.sort(sortParents);
for (var i = 0; i < $elems.length; i++) {
    var $clone = $($elems[i]).clone();
    $("#result").append($clone);
}
```

```css
* { font-family: monospace; }
#origin, #result { border: 1px dashed grey; margin: 2px; padding: 2px; }
#origin { color: green; }
#result { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="origin">
  <span>Original</span>
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="time">20:40</span>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="time">10:40</span>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="time">23:25</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="result">
  <span>Sorted</span>
</div>
```

---

#### Ссылки по теме

- [Array​.prototype​.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [Функция parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 1):

> Как можно на js/jquery сделать сортировку элементов по содержанию дочерних элементов?

Как вариант вот такая сотрировка.

```js
// Выборка дочерних элементов
var times = document.querySelectorAll('.parent .time')
// Сортировка 
newTimes = Array.from(times)
  .map(e => e.innerHTML)
  .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
console.log(newTimes)
// Замена элементов
Object.keys(times).forEach((k) => {
  times[k].innerHTML = newTimes[k]
})
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="time">20:40</span>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <span class="time">10:41</span>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <span class="time">10:40</span>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <span class="time">23:25</span>
</div>
```

---

**UPD**: обновил до версии 1.0.0

```js
// Выборка дочерних элементов
var times = document.querySelectorAll('.parent')
// Сортировка 
newTimes = Array.from(times)
  .map(e => e.innerHTML)
  .sort((a, b) => a.match(/\>(.*)\</)[1].localeCompare(b.match(/\>(.*)\</)[1]));
console.log(newTimes)
// Замена элементов
Object.keys(times).forEach((k) => {
  times[k].innerHTML = newTimes[k]
})
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Первый элемент в оригинальном списке
  <span class="time">20:40</span>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  Второй элемент в оригинальном списке
  <span class="time">10:41</span>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  Третий элемент в оригинальном списке
  <span class="time">10:40</span>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  Четвертый элемент в оригинальном списке
  <span class="time">23:25</span>
</div>
```

---

Comment: Мне кажется ваш скрипт не делает сортировку элементов, а просто перезаписывает значение дочерних элементов [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/russsiq/pen/axeMNR)

Comment: @РустамГимранов обновил, благодарю.